# Understand magic code in Agile Web Development with Rails (4th edition)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I don't understand **5th line** in "line_items_controller.rb" :
I notice the code for Rails 3.1 don't have such line while in code for Rails 3.2 it has such line.
From Java world, It's hard to tell what kind of magic ruby used here :(
I was stuck in understanding Rails document.

e.g.
button_to has signiture **button_to(name, options = {}, html_options = {})**

But in the code, you can add on parameter like

```
<%= button_to 'Empty cart', @cart, :method => :delete, :confirm => 'Are you sure?' %>
```

I suppose @cart shouldn't be there...

```
def create
    @cart = current_cart #this is a function method
    product = Product.find(params[:product_id])
    @line_item = @cart.add_product(product.id)
    @line_item.product = product

    respond_to do |format|
      if @line_item.save
        format.html { redirect_to @line_item.cart }
        format.json { render json: @line_item,
          status: :created, location: @line_item }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @line_item.errors,
          status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
end
```

Full source code for project here:
https://github.com/ilovejs/depot_i/blob/master/app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems like `@cart.add_product(product.id)`if to add a product to the `@cart`, and `@line_item.product = product` is also seems like doing the same thing

its little hard to tell without seeing the code of `Cart` model, however I think

removing the `@line_item.product = product` line should also work without a problem

Answer (score 1):

Replaec:

```
@line_item = @cart.add_product(product.id)
@line_item.product = product
```

with

```
@cart.add_product(product.id)
```

then

```
@line_item
```

references below should probably be @cart.